# Как передать ссылку на приложение с данными

Tags: android, google-play

Хотел сделать функционал,  как в приложение "Купи батон"

Пользователь формирует список продуктов и отправляет его в месенжер с ссылкой. Если данную ссылку открыть, то она введет в GooglePlay, откуда можно установить или открыть приложение, если оно уже установлено. 
Также в открывшемся приложение показывается список с формированным списком продуктов.

Как правильно передать ссылку на приложение с данными и как потом эти данные можно их этого приложения получить? 

Ps копал в сторону deeplink я так понял что этот вариант хорош если только уже приложение уже установлено.

Comment: Диплиинки от гугла, будут выполнять вашу задачу полностью, только вот я не знаю точно, можноли через них передавать данные. https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links

Comment: возможно это приложения с мгновенным запуском.